# Import tables from Postgres into Arcmap

Tags: postgresql, import, arcgis, arcmap

I have set up Esri Geoportal server on linux using this tutorial:

http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/geoportal-server-setup-on-linux.pdf

I have opened phpPgAdmin and imported .csv file into and created tables from those.

Is there any step by step tutorial about how I can import those tables in ArcMap?

How can I import table from Postgresql into ArcMap?

Comment: Have you considered posting GIS questions to [**GIS Stack Exchange**](http://gis.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Generally you don't. Usually the idea is to keep the data in Postgres and dynamically join the data to the map server using their APIs

Comment: @Neil: yes, how can I dynamically accomplish this? I am looking for a tutorial or sth. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as a tutorial goes, I'm not sure if there's a complete end-to-end one.  Depends on what kind of programming  language and which endpoint you wish to use.

For an overview of next steps, look at 
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/geoportal/index.php?title=Post_Deployment_Actions

Also the documentation explains a bit about how to connect using their APIs:
https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Geoportal-server-as-a-broker

I'm assuming you followed your linked-tutoial all the way through and installed the JDBC jar file and configured the xml to connect the database to the geoportal server?

Then it all depends on whether you just need to customize their built-in starter web app to suit your needs, or if you're building something from scratch, etc. Sorry for the non-specific answer but it's just that there are about 1000 possibilities depending on what you are looking to do, so it's somewhat of a broad question.

One last link, check out the customizations page, it may have more of what you're looking for.

https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Customizations#wiki-Integration_with_other_components
\